# Mat-table : add a row between header and body with filter inputs

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I am using Angular Material in a project, do you know if it is possible to define manually a row inside a mat-table? The idea is to add a row containing only inputs to filter the columns directly in the database (not using the filtering options of mat-table).

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr> <!-- this new row -->
   <td><input ...></td>
   <td><input ...></td>
   ...
</tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Have you tried your code and it didn't work? Its seems reasonable to me at first glance. maybe also add the `map-row` directive too

Comment: Hello, thanks, yes I did try it with and without the directive. I think I don't have much choice, I will have to create a second `mat-header-row` with several ng-container for each columns. I didn't want to use it because we have a lot of columns to show.